# ODBC Error Not enough space for parser stacks while trying to insert/Update/Delete data to informix

Tags: database, c#-4.0, odbc, driver, informix

IBM Informix ODBC driver 64 bit - Version:4.10.00.15644

could not execute update query[SQL: delete from table_Name where ColumnName in (? , ?)] could not execute update query[SQL: delete from Table_Name where Column_Namein (? , ?)] ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]General error.Not enough space for parser stacks.

The above error is getting in all crud operations apart from select statement.
Can anyone tell me why this error is occuring. What is the root cause and what is the solution for this?

This error is occuring intermittent but not frequently

thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably do not close some resources on client side. Show us code you use to insert data.

Comment: we are getting data when we are trying to perform operations on huge data also we are using parallel process to do so. As the heap memory is full, is it unable to parse the data that is using heap? Is my analysis right?. Further inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned before, could be your code is not freeing resources properly. Have you tried with latest Informix ODBC driver (CSDK 4.50.FC3). Version '4.10.00.15644' correspond to CSDK 4.10.FC4 which is quite old (~6 years)